# Problema no autoload em teste com PHPUnit e Composer no Windows

Tags: php, windows, composer, php-autoload, phpunit

Estou tendo um problema com o **Composer** no Windows 7.

Desenvolvi um projeto com a seguinte estrutura:

```
Simpla_HTML
|--/src
|    |--/Simpla
|          |--/Html
|               |--/Element.php
/---tests
|    |--/Simpla
|          |--/Html
|               |--/ElementTest.php
|----Vendor
      |---...
```

E no Composer.json defini o autoload da seguinte forma:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Simpla\\": [
            "src/",
            "tests/"
        ]
    }
}
```

O meu teste foi definido assim:

```
<?php

require './vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase as PHPUnit;
use Simpla\Html\Element;

class ElementTest extends PHPUnit{

    public function testElementoPai() {

        $actual = Element::tag('html');

        return $this->assertEquals('<html></html>', $actual->render());
    }
}
```

No entanto, ao tentar testar minha aplicação ocorre o erro abaixo no CMD com o comando *vendor\bin\phpunit tests*:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Simpla\Html\Element' not found in C:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\estudo\Simpla\tests\Simpla\Html\ElementTest.php on line 12
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Simpla\Html\Element' not found in C:\EasyPHP\data\localweb\estudo\Simpla\tests\Simpla\Html\ElementTest.php on line 12
```

Mas, se eu trocar o **require** no meu arquivo de testes **ElementTest.php** por 
`'./src/Simpla/Html/Element.php';` o teste roda normalmente.

Será que estou fazendo algo errado no meu autoload?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A implementação que você está tentando é PSR-0, e não PSR-4.

Tente trocar:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Simpla\\": [
            "src/",
            "tests/"
        ]
    }
}
```

por:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Simpla\\": [
            "src/Simpla/",
            "tests/Simpla/"
        ]
    }
}
```

Fonte: http://seld.be/notes/psr-4-autoloading-support-in-composer

Comment: Já havia tentado essa opção antes e continua o mesmo erro.